# How do I load an Alpine Store with asynchronous values from a fetch call?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, alpine.js

Trying to load an Alpine store with values (a list of arrays) from an API call.  The fetch returns a promise, so looking for the best way to load this diretly:

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.store('myStore', {
        my_data: fetch('/api/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
    })
})
```

I’m not committed to fetch but whatever’s easiest to add to the store directly.

Answer (score 0):

Invert it. Fetch the data first then create the store once it's resolved

```js
document.addEventListener("alpine:init", async () => {
  const res = await fetch("/api/1");
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`);
  }
  Alpine.store("myStore", {
    my_data: await res.json(),
  });
});
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to take the async function in document.addEventListener, I think I can pass it another direction; thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `addEventListener` doesn't care what sort of function you pass in. What makes you think that's a problem?